# iCloud emails not received from Contact Form

Tags: php, forms, email, icloud

I would like to know if anyone has come across this problem.  I have a contact form and php script that I have used many times and it works fine.

However, I need to include an Apple email as a recipient (.icloud.com or .me.com accounts).  On my localhost server, the form always delivers all of the emails but on my live website, they are delivered to all addresses EXCEPT the Apple ones.   I have tested this with at least 10 different non-Apple email addresses and it works without fail but Apple ones just won’t work.  I have tried two different Apple accounts and the emails don't arrive.

My web hosting service tells me from their logs that they are delivered.  So where could they go?  Does Apple somehow filter them out as junk? (they don’t arrive in the spam/junk folder by the way).  I’ve tried to contact Apple to establish if by any chance they are blacklisting the mail server concerned but getting through to the appropriate technical support seems impossible so any ideas would be most appreciated.

Here is the relevant code from the php:

```
$email_to = "enquiry@mywebsite.co.uk, myname@testmail.co.uk, myname@hotmail.com, myname@icloud.com, myname@me.com";


$headers = 'From: '."enquiry@mywebsite.co.uk"."\r\n".
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '."donotreply@mywebsite.co.uk"."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
header('Location: http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/contact_thankyou.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Petro,

Try this and see if you can see if it gives you any more useful info.

```
telnet yourmailhost 25
```

You will see the prompts S, you need to type the responses C.

```
S: 220 smtp2go.com ESMTP Exim
C: HELO mydomain.com
S: 250 Hello mydomain.com
C: MAIL FROM:<sender@mydomain.com>
S: 250 Ok
C: RCPT TO:<recipient@anotherdomain.com>
S: 250 Accepted
C: DATA
S: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
C: Subject: communication
C: From: sender@mydomain.com
C: To: recipient@anotherdomain.com
C: 
C: Bonjour,
C: Do you speak English?
C: Ciao.
C: . 
S: 250 OK
C: QUIT
S: 221 www.sample.com closing connection
```

Did you try a different sender address too; it maybe their mail host is verifying the sender address and isn't liking the reply it gets?